# How can I avoid both aggregate functions and subqueries when GROUP BY'ing a primary key?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Say I have two tables:

- object

  - id
  - name
- object_event

  - id
  - object_id
  - type
  - date

I want to grab all the objects that had an event happen during a date range. I want to get at most a single row for every object, but many events on the same object can happen in the date range. The following query gives me the `id`s I want:

```
SELECT object.id
FROM object
JOIN ON object.id = object_event.object_id
WHERE object_event.date < ...
GROUP BY object.id
```

This is OK, but what if I want the other fields in the object table as well? I can't have aggregate functions on them (`name` is a string), but because `id` is `object`'s primary key, there is a functional dependency saying there is no ambiguity in something like:

```
SELECT object.*
<rest of query same as above>
```

MySQL allows this, but MS SQL does not. I know I can solve this with a subquery, but I would like to avoid that.

Comment: Any reason you don't like subqueries?

Comment: I don't see why you can't just include them in the query if the columns are at the Object scope, as you are already grouping at the most unique column in that table.

Comment: it sounds like DISTINCT might help you. this should work in a normal join, and there is not much wrong with subqueries - if they solve your problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't really want to do a join here, you're instead looking for set inclusion.

Something like this would work better and will be more efficient than implementing a distinct sort or a group by.

```
SELECT O.* 
FROM object O
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM object_event E WHERE date BETWEEN @myDate1 AND @mydate2 AND E.object_id = O.id)
```

Comment: Also, I do note your aversion to subqueries but I assume you mean aggregating/distinct sorting in a joined derived table and not implementing a semi-join. This is actually more efficient than doing a distinct or group by

Comment: OK, I give up :) Seems as they are the only cross-database way.